# How do you change log-linear transformed prediction interval values for a regression back to original scale in r?

Tags: regression, prediction-interval, log-linear

I have a simple regression model where I needed to log-transform the dependent variable because the model residuals were non-normal.  Now my model is ok in that respect.  So, I ran the model.  But, now I have predictions and prediction intervals for each observation in log form.  I want to transform back the predictions and prediction intervals for each observation to the original scale so it makes sense.

Below is my code.  I just applied "exp" to the predict function to transform back. Is this correct?

I do not know if I am doing this correctly because my prediction intervals for each observation are HUGE, different sizes, and the low/high prediction interval points are unequal distances from the prediction value.   Thank you in advance.

```r
log_y <- log(y)
model <- lm(log_y ~ a + b + c, data = data) 
summary(model)
coef(model)
exp(predict(model, newdata = data, interval = "prediction", level = 0.95))
```

Comment: All looks good to me.  All the behaviors you mentioned are as expected as well.  If the wild upper bounds are completely illogical, then it tells you that the lognormal model for $Y$ is not appropriate.

Comment: Thank you @BigBendRegion.  So, I'm stuck at this decision point...When I do not log the dependent variable, the model is easier to interpret, the PIs are reasonable, and the R^2 is slightly better though I know you shouldn't compare.  Can I decide to go with the plain model that is not adjusted to loglinear eventhough the residuals are non-normal and still feel confident in the model?   Is there another approach?  Thank you again!